# W5500 is heating

Tags: drawing, stm32, ethernet, developer-tools

I am coding the w5500 chip with an stm32 board. The product works, but it gets hot even though the w5500 has a 3.3V supply. What would be the reason?

Although I did not use the schematic of the micro development board, there is heating.

How and why can this heating problem occur?

Things to consider for card drawing.
How to solve the heating problem?

Comment: This might be more on-topic on [Electronics StackExchange](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu-sn&q=electronics+stack+exchange) but even there you'd need to give a lot more information for anyone to help you.

Comment: Ethernet controllers often dissipate a lots of heat.